# How can I display a page element based upon security?

Tags: 8, security

If I want to hide or show a DOM element, say a button that can show further information because the logged in user is a manager, how can I do that in Drupal 8?  Do I need to create separate pages for each type of user role?

I saw this but wasn't sure if it was the same thing I was asking,

[How can I change page elements (menu, blocks, etc) based on a chosen 'audience' link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149683/how-can-i-change-page-elements-menu-blocks-etc-based-on-a-chosen-audience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a button only available to users who are admins, put this property in the form element:

```
'#access' => \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access administration pages'),
```

Comment: I know this is old, but does this mean put this between php tags in my html page?  I'm not sure how to to implement this in Drupal 8.